# Why does a Spark Application launch with only a single executor on DC/OS?

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, dcos

I have Spark installed, but when I launch, there is always only one executor allocated to the application (and that is the driver one). I’ve tried everything, but haven’t been able to find out why this is happening.

Here’s the command I used to launch, to give you an idea of all the parameters:

```
dcos spark run --submit-args='--class <class-name> --executor-memory 6g --total-executor-cores 32 --driver-memory 6g <jar-file-source> <application-command-line-params>
```